When I am creating a new virtual server in my VPS server for a new website, I am facing problem in DNS configuration. How to solve it?
enter image description here
enter image description here
I talked to hostinger support but they are not giving proper answer, I tried to solve the issue by checking DNS and trying to auto install SSL but it is not working, when I am searching for my sub domain then the other site which I had first uploaded on the server is opening.

What kind of software are those screenshots from? Is that some kind of control panel system?

yes control panel system virtumin panel VPS
